# I can not install laravel 5.2 version

Tags: php, laravel-5, installation

I want to install new project with 5.2 version but I am getting this error continuously.

Warning: require(C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravelPractice\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravelPractice\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravelPractice\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravelPractice\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravelPractice\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravelPractice\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravelPractice\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravelPractice\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Look like storage permission problem.

**Permissions for storage**

We also need to set correct permissions for storage files in the server. So, we need to give a write permission in the storage directory as follows:

```
$ chmod -R 777 ./storage ./bootstrap
```

or you may use

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 ./storage ./bootstrap
```

**For windows**

Make sure you are an admin user on that computer with writeable access

```
xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\storage needs to be writable
```

Hope it helped you!.

Comment: I cant even install the project.How it can be the permissions problem.By the way didn't workout!

Comment: You have a `composer` installed on your system? @afraz

Comment: Try this one `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel yourDirectory "5.2.*"`.

Comment: Installation just crashes at the beginning. How it can be the permission problem.

Comment: Cloud you please share some more detail what steps you have done for installing `laravel 5.2`.

Comment: @raza yes its installed

Comment: I tried:
composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.2 yourDirectory --prefer-dist &
composer create-project laravel/laravel yourDirectory --prefer-dist  5.2

Comment: Good :) Enjoy @Afraz

Comment: Thanks @raza it worked! By the way this command helped me.

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel yourDirectory "5.2.*"

Comment: I tried but I cant upvote. I am fresh at stackoverflow.

Comment: Hmmmm No problem Glade to helped you :) :)

Comment: May ALLAH bless you with more knowledge and success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use composer to install the vendor components. I.e. run the following command from the Laravel directory, providing you have composer already installed:

```
composer install
```